# Redirecting automatically after Devise log-out with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise, and automatic logout works great.

However, the user is not informed they have been logged out until they make another request, at which point they are redirected to the sign in page.  For AJAX functionality, this is not great, it either fails silently or raises an exception.

Devise wiki doesnt seem to have an example, is there a standard solution to this?  A javascript popup with a countdown timer, that does a redirect if the user doesnt click "keep me logged in"?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing jscript timeout something similar to below.

Some unanswered questions:

- what happens on switching to another tab?
- works in IE?

**application.js**

```
//= require timer

// redirect user after 15 minutes of inactivity - should match Devise.timeout_in + 1 second grace period
$(function() {
    var logout_timer = new Timer(901, 'users/sign_in', window);
    logout_timer.start();

    // restart timer if activity
    $(document).on('keyup keypress blur change mousemove',function(){
      logout_timer.start();
    });

});
```

**timer.js**

```
Timer = function(time_in_secs, path, windowobj) {  // window object must be injected, else location replace will fail specs
  var self = this;    // 'this' not avail in setInterval, must set to local var avail to all functions
  this.state = 'init'
  this.time_remaining = time_in_secs;
  this.timer_id = undefined;

  this.start = function() {
    // if restarting, there will be a timer id.  Clear it to prevent creating a new timer, reset time remaining
    if (this.timer_id !== undefined) {
      this.time_remaining = time_in_secs;
      this.clear_timer(this.timer_id, self); 
    }
    this.state = 'running';

    this.timer_id = setInterval(function() {    // IE any version does not allow args to setInterval.  Therefore, local variables or refer to self obj
      self.time_remaining -= 1;

      // log status every 10 seconds
      if ((self.time_remaining % 10) === 0) {
        console.log("logging user out in " + self.time_remaining + " seconds");
      }

      // when timer runs out, clear timer and redirect
      if ( self.time_remaining <= 0 ) {
        self.clear_timer(self.timer_id, self);
        self.do_redirect(path, windowobj);
      };


    }, 1000);
    return this.timer_id;
  };

  this.clear_timer = function(timer_id, self) {
    self.state = 'stopped';
    clearInterval(self.timer_id);
  }

  this.remaining = function() {
    return this.time_remaining;
  };

  this.do_redirect = function(path, windowobj) {
    console.log("Redirecting to " + path);
    self.state = 'redirecting';
    windowobj.location = path;
  }
}
```